# How to change a variable in a different class? (iOS, Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, class, variables

I have 3 View Controllers in Storyboard. They're named "Letters", "Numbers", and "Other".

What I want is a variable that changes based on which category was used last.

Ex: The user goes to the `Letters` View Controller (`var categories = "Letters"`), and then to the `Other` View Controller, and is able to use the "categories" variable (which is still `"Letters"`). User goes to the `Numbers` View Controller (`var categories = "Numbers"`), and then to the `Other` View Controller, and is able to use the `categories` variable (which is now `"Numbers"`).

I'm not sure if my question and example are clear enough, and if they aren't feel free to ask, and I'll try to further explain.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like you want to pass the 'categories' variable between your view controllers. You can do this when you are presenting each view controller. I will post an answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of ways to do this, but the key concept is that you don't change variables in other classes, you change things in instances (objects) of classes.

I am going to try to keep this simple.

So, you could make a class that has App State kinds of things

```
public class AppState {
    public var category: String? = nil
    public static let shared = AppState()
}
```

Then, anywhere in your code, you can do

```
AppState.shared.category = "Letters"
```

Or

```
if let currentCategory = AppState.shared.category {
    // use currentCategory here
}
```

Doing this is not the *best* way, but it will work and it's simple.  To go a little further, you could learn about dependency injection.  Using that, there would not be a global shared instance, but instead you would pass the appropriate AppState object to objects that needed it.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into it right away. And get back to you if it works the way I need it.

Comment: It works beautifully. However, will the optional get in the way if I use the String in a switch statement, and if so, whats the best way to unwrap it?

Comment: If you have a default category you do not need to make category optional. Assign the default and you do not need unwrapping anymore. That removes the possibility of setting nil accidentally later.

Comment: Oh alright thanks! Not sure why I didn't think of that myself =]

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is by creating a variable named `categories` on each of your view controllers and assigning a value to this before you present your next view controller.

**EXAMPLE:**
**Letters View Controller**

```
var categories = [String]()

    func goToNextViewController()
    {
      let numbersVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "numbersVC")
      numbersVC.categories = self.categories
      self.presentViewController(numbersVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

**Numbers View Controller**

```
var categories = [String]()
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I'll check each answer and see which one suits my program best (most versatile).

Comment: No problem. As Lou Franco hints, global states should be avoided if possible.